# How to allow the traffic for a specific interface in ufw unconditionally

Tags: openvpn, ufw

I've installed OpenVPN and now the firewall (ufw) is blocking the traffic for the client that connects to it. I'm sure of my OpenVPN setup since when I disable the firewall, I can access IPs from my local network and the internet provided through my local network.

This setup is exactly what I wanted. And I believe it is totally safe if I tell my firewall that all the traffic coming from the `tun0` interface (created by OpenVPN) is absolutely trusted (feel free to correct me on this).

But I cannot find the right rule for my ufw so it allows all the traffic to pass through. No matter what I set, the firewall blocks the traffic.

What is the correct rule to tell ufw that some particular interface is fully trusted? (no restriction on the IP and/or port as long as it's coming from or going to that interface)

**[UPDATE]**

These are the rules I've added. For some reason, my requests are still blocked when I connect to the VPN. For example when I try to open a local webpage at http://192.168.1.10. And as soon as I turn off the ufw, it works.

```
$ sudo ufw allow in on tun0
$ sudo ufw allow out on tun0
```

**[UPDATE]**

In case it helps, here's the complete list of my ufw's rules:

```
$ sudo ufw numbered
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5900/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere on tun0           ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5900/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Anywhere (v6) on tun0      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

5900/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun0          
5900/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on tun0
```

Comment: iptables allows also a generic like tun±

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with how OpenVPN sets up the **tun0** interface, but I ran into the same issue with a similar configuration (phantun on **tun0**).

In short, I suspect what you need are `ufw route` rules. The VPN on **tun0** acts as a "separate machine" (per phantun docs) so the connections to/from it are not inbound or outbound from the perspective of UFW, but forwarded ones.

For example, if your main network interface is **eth0**, then rules such as `ufw route allow in on eth0 out on tun0` and `ufw route allow in on tun0 out on eht0` should help.

The situation with OpenVPN may be different, so these might not work for you. Also, you may want to narrow down the scope of these rules for security reasons.